# Как закрыть всплывающее окно Telegram с помощью selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

При переходе по ссылке в телеграмм, появляется окно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как нажать кнопку "Отмена"?